# PPT slides to images

Tags: c#, ms-office

I am using Office 07 PIA to convert the ppt into images in C#.

The slides are properly converted into images.

Now, while individual slides are converted into images, I was hoping for a workaround that could also convert the animations within slides too. I want to play these ppt [converted to images] in my custom application and not in MS PowerPoint.

I would really appreciate any help!

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's pretty simple:

**Office 2002**

```
using Microsoft.Office.Core;
using PowerPoint;

ApplicationClass pptApplication = new ApplicationClass();

Presentation pptPresentation = pptApplication.Presentations.Open("myfile.ppt", MsoTriState.msoFalse,
MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoFalse);

pptPresentation.Slides.Item(1).Export("slide.jpg", "jpg", 320, 240);
```

**Office 2003**

```
using Microsoft.Office.Core;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint;

ApplicationClass pptApplication = new ApplicationClass();
Presentation pptPresentation = pptApplication.Presentations.Open("myfile.ppt", MsoTriState.msoFalse,
MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoFalse);

pptPresentation.Slides.Item[1].Export("slide.jpg", "jpg", 320, 240);
```

**Image Output Quality**

```
pptPresentation.Slides.Item[1].Export("slide.png", "PNG", 1024, 768);
```

Comment: this would just convert the slides into images, right? I also want to convert the animations within the slides to some presentable format.

Comment: yes, hmm i don't know what about animations, maybe it will split animations to different images, need to test, but this is functionality which provided to us by MS, any other functionality we should create by our selves :/

Comment: I have tested, it does not create images for animations. Yes, we need to do the "extra" functionalities ourselves and thus I am asking for some leads in to going about it. I'm doing this for a college project.

Comment: also it's possible to convert it to flash, and then you should have possibility to reflect animation in a nice way. Here is an free trial SDK: http://www.ispringsolutions.com/products/ispring_sdk.html

Comment: also there is a way to catch events, so maybe they could help you in some way: http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=308825

Comment: I shall check out the KB. Thanks mate :)

Comment: so this requires office to be installed on server, and lots of other configurations. i posted it here stackoverflow.com/a/40385136/1386991

Comment: From my understanding this will also cause an "Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program" exception if running as a service or unattended. As "Microsoft does not currently recommend and does not support automation of MS Office applications" > See [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42083799/insufficient-memory-exception-in-interop-library-when-exporting-images-of-ppt-sl)

Answer (score 3):

**The question is difficult to understand.**

> However from what I gather you are
>   trying to display PowerPoint Slides in
>   your custom C# Application?

### Solution 1:

Convert each PPT slide into HTML format (this should be possible from PowerPoint e.g. save as).

Drop a web-Browser component onto your application, and then simply point to the HTML file(s). You could even get the 'next' abd 'prev' buttons to go to the next 'slide' or bind it to mouse click.

As for videos, I'm not sure how exporting HTML from PowerPoint would handle this, you may be able to convert the Video to FLV, and imbed a basic FLV flash player into the HTML 'slide' file(s)

### Extended Solution 1:

To deal with the animations (PowerPoint Fades etc) you could use this free product [**iSpring**](http://www.ispringsolutions.com/). This converts PPT to Flash (including animations and videos I believe). Which can then be embedded into a HTML file and played back on a web browser Component.

**Edit 2:** iSpring is no longer free

Comment: See, I have a Picture Box that displays the ppt slides that are converted into images. Now the animations within the slides are not accounted for in this process. I was hunting for a workaround for the same!

Comment: Are you talking about PowerPoint Animations (e.g. transitions/fades etc?) or video animations?

Comment: Yes, I am talking about the PowerPoint Animations.

Comment: Actually I am creating the images from slides at runtime, so want to do stuff programmatically. anyways thanks for the link.

Comment: @Darknight: iSpringFree is still free, it's just at a different URL: http://www.ispringfree.com/

Answer (score 0):

you need to set this properties for this

-Right click  package- Interop, in the solution explorer under your project References.
-Click properties.
-And there should be the option there for **Embed Interop Assembly**.
-Set it to **False**

**Code-**

```cs
FileInfo objfile = new FileInfo(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
if (objfile.Extension.Equals(".pptx"))
{
    ApplicationClass pptApplication = new ApplicationClass();
    Presentation pptPresentation = pptApplication.Presentations.Open(objfile.FullName, MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoFalse);
    pptPresentation.Export(objfile.FullName, "jpg", Int32.Parse(pptPresentation.SlideMaster.Width.ToString()), Int32.Parse(pptPresentation.SlideMaster.Height.ToString()));
}
```