# How to convert PowerPoint (.ppt, .pptx) to several images of each slide?

Tags: c#, .net, powerpoint

Do you guys have some .Net libraries which has ability to convert a PowerPoint Presentation file into images?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PPT slides to images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972263/ppt-slides-to-images)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do check
 [PPT slides to images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972263/ppt-slides-to-images)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733347/is-it-possible-to-convert-powerpoint-to-images-programatically

Answer (score 11):

Using add reference to  `Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.dll`. To convert PowerPoint slides to PNG images:

```cs
PowerPoint.Presentation pptPresentation = pptApplication.Presentations.Open2007(FILE);
foreach (PowerPoint.Slide pptSlide in pptPresentation.Slides)
{
   pptSlide.Export(NEWNAME, "PNG", 1024, 768);
}
```

Comment: so this requires office to be installed on server, and lots of other configurations. i posted it here http://stackoverflow.com/a/40385136/1386991

Comment: var pptPresentation = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application();

Answer (score 1):

Please see if [Aspose.Slides for .NET](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.slides-for-.net/default.aspx) can help you in this scenario. This component allows you to [convert Powerpoint slides to images](http://www.aspose.com/documentation/.net-components/aspose.slides-for-.net/creating-slide-thumbnail-image-1.html). It doesn't require MS Office to be installed on the system.

Disclosure: I work as developer evangelist at Aspose.