# Showing ppt in unity or converting to image

Tags: unity-game-engine, monogame

Can anyone explain how I can show ppt presentation in unity application?
I did many research on that but found that unity does not support ppt.
So think to convert ppt into an image but not get any success so want to know that Is it possible to convert ppt file to image in unity if yes then how?

Comment: Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4316845/3785314)?