# Display power point docs in WinForms app

Tags: c#, winforms, powerpoint

What is the best solution to display/integrate and manipulate PowerPoint documents in .NET WinFroms?

Comment: You want to be able to edit document in winform or just show slide show?

Comment: show slide show and take actions when a slide is clicked, etc

Comment: I did something familiar few years ago. I exported slides as images and then manipulated them(show next image, show previous, draw on them etc.)

Comment: if you need animations then images is not solution :)

Comment: What solution did you used for converting PowerPoint slides in images?

Comment: try [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972263/ppt-slides-to-images/2972350#2972350) suggested solution. I don't have code right now and don't remember how I did it in my project :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

once there was the **DSOFramer** which has been retired, here what MS's folk said in forums:

> DSOFramer Control has been retired. DSOFramer was a sample and is not
>   supported. There will be no further updates to DSOFramer and KB 311765
>   is been taken down.  Office was never meant to run in embedded mode.
>   There are many known issues when Office is embedded.
>
> Besides DsoFramer, you can also use the WebBrowser embedded in Winform
>   or ASP.NET and navigate to an Office document. But that is also an
>   embedded using which considered not supported and may cause some known
>   issues.
>
> Best regards, Ji Zhou - MSFT Microsoft Online Community Support

I would **try** embedding the web browser control and pointing it to the .ppt (or .pps) file and see how it works.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Powerpoint Namespace should be right for you.

For that you must have installed Powerpoint on the developing and executing machine.