# How to generate thumbnail image for a PPTX file in C#?

Tags: c#, powerpoint, openxml-sdk

Is there any way to use the OpenXML library to automatically create a thumbnail image for a PPTX file?  I am building a small C# ASP.NET web application that is used to build PPTX files from a library of PPTX files.  One of the requirements is to show a thumbnail image for each PPTX file in the library.  I would like to automate this as the people that will be using the system don't know how to create screen shots.

Answer (score 1):

There's a commercial library available that can generate thumbnails of slides in presentations. So at least you know it's possible: http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/slidesnet/Creating+Slides+Thumbnail+Image

Comment: Thanks - yes I have read about the ASPOSE library.  I was hoping to be able to code it manually and not have to purchase that product.

Comment: +1 for balance: there is nothing wrong in giving a commercial link.

Answer (score 1):

Pptx file already have it, unziping the file you can find id. ;)

Comment: Just had a look at a couple of pptx files. Some of them seem to have it, others don't; haven't yet worked out what causes the thumbnail to be created or skipped, though, or how to build one if it's missing...

Comment: Can you reference the PowerPoint dll in your web app instead of using OpenXml? If yes this could be a way... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972263/ppt-slides-to-images

Comment: @tobriand: as it can be read here `https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd721893%28v=office.12%29.aspx` it seems like you have to enable preview screenshot when saving the presentation.

Comment: Thanks Tobias! That answers my outstanding question. Of course in the end the project took a step further, wanting to be able to preview a number of slides, so ended up having to

Comment: once the file is unzipped, where are the thumbnails located?