# Programmatically change/add thumbnail of pptx powerpoint. With Openxml sdk?

Tags: c#, powerpoint, thumbnails, openxml

I use openxml sdk 2.5 in combination with the power tools by Eric White. I've managed to create dynamic pptx presentations using template files. (In C#)
Unfortunately the thumbnail gets lost during the process. 
**Is there any way to (re)create the thumbnail of a pptx-file using openxml or power tools?** 
 I successfully wrote some code that changes an existing thumbnail with an image. But when there is is no thumbnail it gives me a *System.NullReferenceException*. Here is the code:

```
using OpenXmlPowerTools;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class AddThumbnail_
    {
        public static void ReplaceThumbnail(ThumbnailPart thumbnailPart, string newThumbnail)
        {
            using (
                FileStream imgStream = new FileStream(newThumbnail, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                thumbnailPart.FeedData(imgStream);
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var templatePresentation = "Modified.pptx";
            var outputPresentation = "Modified.pptx";
            var baPresentation = File.ReadAllBytes(templatePresentation);
            var pmlMainPresentation = new PmlDocument("Main.pptx", baPresentation);
            OpenXmlMemoryStreamDocument streamDoc = new OpenXmlMemoryStreamDocument(pmlMainPresentation);
            PresentationDocument document = streamDoc.GetPresentationDocument();
            var thumbNailPart = document.ThumbnailPart;
            ReplaceThumbnail(thumbNailPart, @"C:\Path\to\image\image.jpg");
            document.SaveAs(outputPresentation);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
I realize this question has been asked before ([How to generate thumbnail image for a PPTX file in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11146072/how-to-generate-thumbnail-image-for-a-pptx-file-in-c)) and the answer is "enable preview screenshot when saving the presentation" but this would mean I'd have to open every pptx and manually set this flag. I would appreciate a C# solution.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the thumbnail has never existed then the `ThumbnailPart` won't necessarily exist in the document and so the `thumbNailPart` variable in your code will be null. In that scenario, as well as setting the image for the `ThumbnailPart` you need to add the part itself.

*Normally* when using the OpenXml SDK you would call the `AddPart` method passing in a `new ThumbnailPart` but for some reason the [`ThumbnailPart` constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.packaging.thumbnailpart.thumbnailpart.aspx) is `protected internal` and thus not accessible to you. Instead, there is an [`AddThumbnailPart`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.packaging.presentationdocument.addthumbnailpart(v=office.15).aspx) method on the `PresentationDocument` which will create a new `ThumbnailPart`. The `AddThumbnailPart` method takes either a string for the content type or a [`ThumbnailPartType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.packaging.thumbnailparttype.aspx) enum member.

Adding the following to your code should fix your issue:

```
if (document.ThumbnailPart == null)
    document.AddThumbnailPart(ThumbnailPartType.Jpeg);

var thumbNailPart = document.ThumbnailPart;
```