# Generate image from PowerPoint slide

Tags: c#, xml, powerpoint, openxml, openxml-sdk

I use [Open XML SDK](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK) tool to parse pptx-files. Now I am going to develop my own .NET library/tool to generate an image from a PowerPoint slide. Open XML SDK in principle is not for such tasks, and **I do not know where to start research?**.

- maybe to solve it better to use another programming language, for example, C++ (I also know it) with some library?
- or it may be necessary intermediate convert pptx into some another format, for example, HTML and only then to image?

I also tried to investigate [Aspose.Slides](https://products.aspose.com/slides?gclid=Cj0KCQjwjrvpBRC0ARIsAFrFuV-P5URBPwX3LFTdFMYKSMjD7h7kNXThYwvzXHzNHkE-qgN32OjAO58aAvduEALw_wcB) and [Spire.Presentation](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Introduce/presentation-for-net-introduce.html) libraries' dependencies in NuGet to know what they use to an image generation, but these attempts did not succeed.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a good starting point: [Presentation to image conversion](https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/presentation/presentation-to-image) 
The cited versions are old, but the syntax is still the same: [PPT slides to images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972263/ppt-slides-to-images)

Comment: Topics which you specified describe creating an image via Syncfusion and Interop.PowerPoint libraries. These tools are like Aspose and Spire, which I above-mentioned. I am interesting a little bit **low** thinks: which algorithms and tools these libraries use.

Answer (score -1):

My mistake, I misunderstood the end goal.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood, but actually, I already use reverse engineering during entire research pptx-file. But have not idea how to use it for my problem. You talked about _"... a known image in PowerPoint you've already parsed"_. I want to remind you that I am trying to save **whole slide layout in an image file**, instead parse separate picture elements. Can you give more information about what you mentioned.