# Generate Powerpoint Slide images for add-in without performance problems

Tags: c#, vsto, powerpoint, add-in

I'm trying to make an add-in for PowerPoint. For this I need a slide preview of the PowerPoint slides (just like Powerpoint itself has at the left, with the small preview pictures). The only way I can think of is to use the Export() method to create images of the slides and cache them on the user's hard drive and then use them. However, I don't find this option very nice. I also think that I will run into performance problems with it relatively quickly.
Is there a better way so that I do not have to read/write to the user's hard drive?

And I'm sorry, I'm completely new to VSTO, C# ......
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Exporting slides is the most reliable way, unfortunately. You can read about alternatives on the [PPT slides to images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972263/ppt-slides-to-images) thread.

Also, you may consider taking screenshots programmatically in C#, see [Capture screenshot of active window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163761/capture-screenshot-of-active-window).